# Use private Qt api (QWindowSystemEventHandler/QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::WindowSystemEvent) with PySide2

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt5, pyside2

In short, i am trying to record and playback native window events for testing purposes, because doing the same with regular `QEvent` feels unfeasible as it would require every `QObject` in the quick scene to have a unique `QObject::name` that should be reassigned identically at every run.
This can easily get out of hand when there are views involved (even tree views) and everything visible is an item.

So the idea was to track native window events, that is possible through `QCoreApplication::installNativeEventFilter`.

For the reinjection, however, it's a whole different story.
By digging into the Qt source code, i ended up finding `QWindowSystemEventHandler` that seems what i need.
Although private headers, it seems to be a public and static API that could be easily called, also in `QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::installWindowSystemEventHandler`.

The problem is i don't know how to access it from PySide2. Is this at all possible, and if not, would there be any alternative way to do this?

If not, could i in principle modify the PySide2 wrapper to expose these classes and rebuild it?

Comment: Your reason for trying to do that is unclear to me. By "testing purposes" do you mean unit testing? If so, maybe the problem is in the way the test has been implemented (or even designed). Your description is a bit vague, though, and I'm under the impression that you're not generating deterministic (or "determinable") objects. Can you clarify what you're actually trying to do and what makes the usage of native events required? Note that there are tools for proper testing in Qt (via the QTest module and [pytest-qt](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-qt)).

Comment: I mean UI testing. And while, in principle, objects are deterministic, there are a few views involved, and being this a QML application, every visual entry becomes an item that would have to be labeled individually.
This is possible, but i was hoping for an easier, higher level approach, where i could simply record and reinject window system events (namely mouse-related and key-related events), which would greatly simplify the ui testing architecture.

My next approach  is likely converting mouse events coordinate into root item coordinates, and replaying them into the root window..

Comment: Then I suggest you to check QTest and pytest-qt as their purpose is (also) exactly intended for what you want to do.

Comment: @musicamante thanks for the suggestion. I checked the packages you suggested, but it doesn't seem they include any facility for recording events to replay.
Moreover, pytest-qt seems to work only with widgets. There's a pytest-qml, but it seems to anyway suffer from the same limitations.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, it seems that the easiest way to achieve what i asked would be to create a custom module, and bindings for it, like explained in https://www.kdab.com/creating-python-bindings-for-qt-libraries/ and https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/shiboken2/examples/samplebinding.html